# Filtering the two frequencies with highest amplitudes of a signal in the frequency domain

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have tried to filter the two frequencies which have the highest amplitudes. I am wondering if the result is correct, because the filtered signal seems less smooth than the original?
Is it correct that the output of the FFT-function contains the fundamental frequency A0/ C0, and is it correct to include it in the search of the highest amplitude (it is indeed the highest!) ?

My code (based on my professors and collegues code, and I did not understand every detail so far):

```
# signal
data = np.loadtxt("profil.txt")
t = data[:,0]
x = data[:,1]
x = x-np.mean(x)           # Reduce signal to mean
n = len(t)
max_ind = int(n/2-1)       
dt = (t[n-1]-t[0])/(n-1)   
T =    n*dt                  
df = 1./T                  

# Fast-Fourier-Transformation
c     = 2.*np.absolute(fft(x))/n    #get the power sprectrum c from the array of complex numbers
c[0]  = c[0]/2.                     #correction for c0 (fundamental frequency)
f = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=dt)       
a = fft(x).real
b = fft(x).imag
n_fft = len(a)

# filter 
p = np.ones(len(c))
p[c[0:int(len(c)/2)].argsort()[int(len(c)/2-1)]] = 0         #setting the positions of p to 0 with 
p[c[0:int(len(c)/2)].argsort()[int(len(c)/2-2)]] = 0         #the indices from the argsort function
print(c[0:int(len(c)/2-1)].argsort()[int(n_fft/2-2)])        #over the first half of the c array,  
ab_filter_2 = fft(x)                                        #because the second half contains the 
ab_filter_2.real = a*p                                      #negative frequencies.  
ab_filter_2.imag = b*p
x_filter2 = ifft(ab_filter_2)*2
```

I do not quite get the whole deal about FFT returning negative and positive frequencies. I know they are just mirrored, but then why can I not search over the whole array? And the iFFT function works with an array of just the positive frequencies?

The resulting plot: (blue original, red is filtered):

[image]

Comment: Please don’t edit the question after you’ve received an answer, at least not in a way that invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is very wasteful:

```
a = fft(x).real
b = fft(x).imag
```

You’re computing the FFT twice for no good reason. You compute it a 3rd time later, and you already computed it once before. You should compute it only once, not 4 times. The FFT is the most expensive part of your code.

Then:

```
ab_filter_2 = fft(x)
ab_filter_2.real = a*p
ab_filter_2.imag = b*p
x_filter2 = ifft(ab_filter_2)*2
```

Replace all of that with:

```
out = ifft(fft(x) * p)
```

Here you do the same thing twice:

```
p[c[0:int(len(c)/2)].argsort()[int(len(c)/2-1)]] = 0
p[c[0:int(len(c)/2)].argsort()[int(len(c)/2-2)]] = 0
```

But you set only the left half of the filter. It is important to make a symmetric filter. There are two locations where `abs(f)` has the same value (up to rounding errors!), there is a positive and a negative frequency that go together. Those two locations should have the same filter value (actually complex conjugate, but you have a real-valued filter so the difference doesn’t matter in this case).

I’m unsure what that indexing does anyway. I would split out the statement into shorter parts on separate lines for readability.

I would do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

x = ...
x -= np.mean(x)
fft_x = np.fft.fft(x)
c = np.abs(fft_x)  # no point in normalizing, doesn't change the order when sorting

f = c[0:len(c)//2].argsort()
f = f[-2:] # the last two elements are the indices to the largest two frequency components
p = np.zeros(len(c))
p[f] = 1   # preserve the largest two components
p[-f] = 1  # set the same components counting from the end

out = np.fft.ifft(fft_x * p).real
# note that np.fft.ifft(fft_x * p).imag is approximately zero if the filter is created correctly
```

> Is it correct that the output of the FFT-function contains the fundamental frequency A0/ C0 […]?

In principle yes, but you subtracted the mean from the signal, effectively setting the fundamental frequency (DC component) to 0.

Comment: thanks, I have learned various things from this. But did you see that I want to eliminate the highest two amplitudes? In that case p it should be np.ones() and p[f] = 0 , correct?

Comment: I am struggling to understand your last line. Is the output of ifft() not an array of real numbers? In my mind ifft(fft_x.real * p) would make more sense.

Comment: @MoritzFarol I misunderstood. Yes, indeed, set everything to 1 and the selected frequencies to 0 to filter out those frequencies. The FFT and IFFT are complex-to-complex transforms. If the input is real-valued, it is still interpreted as complex, with zero imaginary component. The output is always complex. In this case, the imaginary component is 0, except for rounding errors (ie it’s very small), we need to manually discard it. If you discard the imaginary part of the input to IFFT, you will get a complex-valued result with non-zero imaginary component.